# What is the fastest way to select a row of a data frame with a specific ID value?

Tags: r, optimization, dataframe

Right now I am analyzing some data using

```
row = dataset[dataset$id == id1,]
```

And

```
row = subset(dataset,id == id1)
```

where all of the id values are integers.

However, I have had disappointingly slow results when doing this with larger data sets.  Is there any way that I can speed up this specific task?

Comment: please add context and an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `data.table`, we can set key on a column which physically reorders the data by the column specified in increasing order, which allows us to subset then by using binary search.

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(data1), id)[.(id1)]
```

Alternatively, from data.table versions 1.9.4+, subsets of the form `DT[x == .]` and `DT[x %in% .]` are both optimised internally to create an index automatically and then use binary search to subset on successive runs, which is incredibly fast (see benchmarks below).

```
setDT(data1)[id == id1] # internally optimised to generate index automatically
```

Have a look at [this post](http://www.openanalytics.eu/blog/need-processing-speed-datatable) for more info.

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 data1 <- data.frame(id= sample(1:6, 25, replace=TRUE), val=rnorm(25))
 id1 <- 5L
```

PS: `setDT()` converts the data.frame to data.table by reference.

---

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(29)
dat2 <- data.frame(id= sample(1:100, 1e8, replace=TRUE), val=rnorm(1e8))

# data.frame subset in base R
system.time(dat2[dat2$id == id1,])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  6.287   0.646   7.081 

# base R like syntax on data.table; create index and subset using binary search
system.time(setDT(dat2)[id == id1])
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.646   0.232   0.889 
# successive runs are incredibly fast!
# 0.037   0.002   0.039
# 0.040   0.002   0.042 

# alternatively set key once 
system.time(setkey(setDT(dat2), id))
#  2.908   0.499   3.440 
# and use binary search explicitly
system.time(dat2[.(id1)])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.009   0.002   0.012
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are the comparisons between base([) and dplyr(filter):

```
set.seed(29)
dat2 <- data.frame(id= sample(1:6, 3e6, replace=TRUE), val=rnorm(3e6))
library(dplyr)
system.time(dplyr::filter(dat2, id==5))
 user  system elapsed 
0.029   0.004   0.033 
system.time(dat2[dat2$id==5,])
 user  system elapsed 
0.236   0.012   0.248
```